# How to change TARGET DIRECTORY/path of installation for EXE file during SILENT installation

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, automation, silent-installer, cab

I am trying to **silent install exe softwares** while **changing the target directory** during installation.

**I am not able to change the path/directoy during installment.**

I am aware of switches available for exe files, i have attached the same for the exe i am trying to install , it seem to come under
**EDITED**
*Advanced Installer*>>
**(Self-Extracting Microsoft CAB archive)**

**Command Switches:** /extract:path ; /log[:path] ; /lang:lcid ;/quiet ; /passive ; /norestart ; /forcerestat

The various commands/block i tried:
**Python**

```
p = subprocess.Popen(r'path\file.exe /quiet /v"INSTALLDIR=\"path""', shell=True)
```

```
p = subprocess.Popen(r'path\file.exe /quiet TARGETDIR="path""')
```

I am facing the same problem with **powershell**.

Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There dosent seem to be any Target/path usable with AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe,
the only workaround i found was to use **/extract** to get the **msi** out of the **exe** then use **@mklement0** suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: This answer does *not* solve joy's problem, but it should work for *MSI-based* (Windows Installer-based) installer executables created with Advanced Installer.

---

[The Advanced Installer documentation](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/folder-paths.html) indicates that `APPDIR` is the name of the property that for MSI-based executables you can override from the command line (untested):

Python:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(r'path\file.exe /quiet APPDIR="path"', shell=True)
```

PowerShell, assuming you want to wait for the installation to finish:

```
Start-Process -Wait 'path\file.exe' '/quiet APPDIR="path"'
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, i tried setting APPDIR but it does not seem to work. later I came across this software **Ultimate Silent Switch Finder** using it i surprisingly found the packaging technology to be **Self-Extracting Microsoft CAB archive** not advance installer which i mistakenly took while comparing the switches.. and worst  i cant seem to find the exact documentation regarding this . I have modified my question above including the exe driver i am working with -**AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe**

Comment: @joy, I've updated the answer to clarify that it only applies to MSI-based Advanced Installer executables, which may still be helpful to future readers. As for documentation: It is [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/912203/description-of-the-command-line-switches-that-are-supported-by-a-softw), but it doesn't tell you much more than you already know. Have you experimented with `/extract`? I'm unclear on its exact purpose (temporary extraction location vs. installation dir.)

Comment: Thats great. As for the exact function of ` /extract` it seems to extract software update package, you might like to check here for clarification [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/832475/description-of-the-new-features-in-the-package-installer-for-windows-s). However i dont think any of the switches provided under the exe helps to change target directory.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @joy. So the answer may be that you simply cannot change the install directory at installation time. It may not be an option for you, but creating MSI-based executables instead could solve the problem.

Comment: sadly i am starting to feel the same, ill keep the post open hopefully someone can shed some light in near future. About creating MSI-based executables as far as i know i can make use of some free utility tool like msi wrapper or advance installer itself, else get the MSI package for the exe, which i highly doubt is available incase of my exe. Apart from the mentioned is there anything else i can work with for easy conversion/creation of MSI-based executables as per your understanding

Comment: @joy: Sorry, I'm also out of ideas, but I'm not well-versed in installer technologies. The only other thing I can think of is to move the installation directory _after_ the installation, but I presume that is impractical, because it would require you to modify any registry entries / configuration-file entries that refer to the original directory. One more though - no idea if it would work: create a symlink that points to your custom location in the original location, but that would only work if the installer uses that link as-is, without trying to recreate the dir.

Comment: No issue, thanks for your time and help. As for creating a symlink i have never tied that but if its for pointing to the already created directory than that would be impractical for me as i dont plan on utilizing any space in the default directory.

Comment: My pleasure, @joy. Re symlink: I meant the other way around: create a symlink where the installer will try to write to, and hope that it uses that symlink and therefore causes the files copied there to be redirected to your custom location.

Answer (score 0):

Switches are available according to installer software the product is built with. As an example, Puppet installer exe can be passed parameters via Powershell this way - you may be able to leverage this syntax with your installer.

```
            Start-Process -FilePath C:\temp\puppet-agent-x64-latest.msi -ArgumentList "/qn /norestart -L* c:\temp\mylog.txt" -wait
```

Comment: thanks for the immediate answer, yes i tried the same syntax it worked for silent installation, but what i am looking for is to change the path/directory of installation.

Comment: As @mklement0 said, you need to set the value of the property APPDIR, just as you can see in his examples above.

Comment: @BogdanMitrache it did not work as the packaging technology seem to be **Self-Extracting Microsoft CAB archive** and not advance installer, i have updated my earlier question along with the exact driver i am working with.